# Advanced Network Image

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

This happened after upgrading flutter

Compiler message:

```
../../../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_advanced_networkimage-0.5.0/lib/src/provide
r/flutter_advanced_networkimage.dart:143:24: Error: The method 'AdvancedNetworkImage.load' has fewer positional
arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.

  ImageStreamCompleter load(AdvancedNetworkImage key) {
                       ^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:403:24: Context: This is the
overridden method ('load').
  ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
                       ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
Failed to build bundle.
```

Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max. Below is my code

````
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Codec;
import 'dart:ui' show Size, Locale, TextDirection, hashValues;

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import '_network_image_io.dart'
  if (dart.library.html) '_network_image_web.dart' as network_image;
import 'binding.dart';
import 'image_cache.dart';
import 'image_stream.dart';


@immutable
class ImageConfiguration {

  const ImageConfiguration({
    this.bundle,
    this.devicePixelRatio,
    this.locale,
    this.textDirection,
    this.size,
    this.platform,
  });

  ImageConfiguration copyWith({
    AssetBundle bundle,
    double devicePixelRatio,
    Locale locale,
    TextDirection textDirection,
    Size size,
    String platform,
  }) {
    return ImageConfiguration(
      bundle: bundle ?? this.bundle,
      devicePixelRatio: devicePixelRatio ?? this.devicePixelRatio,
      locale: locale ?? this.locale,
      textDirection: textDirection ?? this.textDirection,
      size: size ?? this.size,
      platform: platform ?? this.platform,
    );
  }

  /// The preferred [AssetBundle] to use if the [ImageProvider] needs one and
  /// does not have one already selected.
  final AssetBundle bundle;

  /// The device pixel ratio where the image will be shown.
  final double devicePixelRatio;

  /// The language and region for which to select the image.
  final Locale locale;

  /// The reading direction of the language for which to select the image.
  final TextDirection textDirection;

  /// The size at which the image will be rendered.
  final Size size;


  final TargetPlatform platform;

  static const ImageConfiguration empty = ImageConfiguration();

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType)
      return false;
    final ImageConfiguration typedOther = other;
    return typedOther.bundle == bundle
        && typedOther.devicePixelRatio == devicePixelRatio
        && typedOther.locale == locale
        && typedOther.textDirection == textDirection
        && typedOther.size == size
        && typedOther.platform == platform;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(bundle, devicePixelRatio, locale, size, platform);

  @override
  String toString() {
    final StringBuffer result = StringBuffer();
    result.write('ImageConfiguration(');
    bool hasArguments = false;
    if (bundle != null) {
      if (hasArguments)
        result.write(', ');
      result.write('bundle: $bundle');
      hasArguments = true;
    }
    if (devicePixelRatio != null) {
      if (hasArguments)
        result.write(', ');
      result.write('devicePixelRatio: ${devicePixelRatio.toStringAsFixed(1)}');
      hasArguments = true;
    }
    if (locale != null) {
      if (hasArguments)
        result.write(', ');
      result.write('locale: $locale');
      hasArguments = true;
    }
    if (textDirection != null) {
      if (hasArguments)
        result.write(', ');
      result.write('textDirection: $textDirection');
      hasArguments = true;
    }
    if (size != null) {
      if (hasArguments)
        result.write(', ');
      result.write('size: $size');
      hasArguments = true;
    }
    if (platform != null) {
      if (hasArguments)
        result.write(', ');
      result.write('platform: ${describeEnum(platform)}');
      hasArguments = true;
    }
    result.write(')');
    return result.toString();
  }
}


typedef DecoderCallback = Future<ui.Codec> Function(Uint8List bytes, {int cacheWidth, int cacheHeight});


@optionalTypeArgs
abstract class ImageProvider<T> {
  /// Abstract const constructor. This constructor enables subclasses to provide
  /// const constructors so that they can be used in const expressions.
  const ImageProvider();


  ImageStream resolve(ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    assert(configuration != null);
    final ImageStream stream = ImageStream();
    T obtainedKey;
    bool didError = false;
    Future<void> handleError(dynamic exception, StackTrace stack) async {
      if (didError) {
        return;
      }
      didError = true;
      await null; // wait an event turn in case a listener has been added to the image stream.
      final _ErrorImageCompleter imageCompleter = _ErrorImageCompleter();
      stream.setCompleter(imageCompleter);
      imageCompleter.setError(
        exception: exception,
        stack: stack,
        context: ErrorDescription('while resolving an image'),
        silent: true, // could be a network error or whatnot
        informationCollector: () sync* {
          yield DiagnosticsProperty<ImageProvider>('Image provider', this);
          yield DiagnosticsProperty<ImageConfiguration>('Image configuration', configuration);
          yield DiagnosticsProperty<T>('Image key', obtainedKey, defaultValue: null);
        },
      );
    }


    final Zone dangerZone = Zone.current.fork(
      specification: ZoneSpecification(
        handleUncaughtError: (Zone zone, ZoneDelegate delegate, Zone parent, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
          handleError(error, stackTrace);
        }
      )
    );
    dangerZone.runGuarded(() {
      Future<T> key;
      try {
        key = obtainKey(configuration);
      } catch (error, stackTrace) {
        handleError(error, stackTrace);
        return;
      }
      key.then<void>((T key) {
        obtainedKey = key;
        final ImageStreamCompleter completer = PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.putIfAbsent(
          key,
          () => load(key, PaintingBinding.instance.instantiateImageCodec),
          onError: handleError,
        );
        if (completer != null) {
          stream.setCompleter(completer);
        }
      }).catchError(handleError);
    });
    return stream;
  }


  Future<bool> evict({ ImageCache cache, ImageConfiguration configuration = ImageConfiguration.empty }) async {
    cache ??= imageCache;
    final T key = await obtainKey(configuration);
    return cache.evict(key);
  }


  Future<T> obtainKey(ImageConfiguration configuration);


  @protected
  ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);

  @override
  String toString() => '$runtimeType()';
}


@immutable
class AssetBundleImageKey {

  const AssetBundleImageKey({
    @required this.bundle,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.scale,
  }) : assert(bundle != null),
       assert(name != null),
       assert(scale != null);


  final AssetBundle bundle;

  /// The key to use to obtain the resource from the [bundle]. This is the
  /// argument passed to [AssetBundle.load].
  final String name;

  /// The scale to place in the [ImageInfo] object of the image.
  final double scale;

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType)
      return false;
    final AssetBundleImageKey typedOther = other;
    return bundle == typedOther.bundle
        && name == typedOther.name
        && scale == typedOther.scale;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(bundle, name, scale);

  @override
  String toString() => '$runtimeType(bundle: $bundle, name: "$name", scale: $scale)';
}

/// A subclass of [ImageProvider] that knows about [AssetBundle]s.
///
/// This factors out the common logic of [AssetBundle]-based [ImageProvider]
/// classes, simplifying what subclasses must implement to just [obtainKey].
abstract class AssetBundleImageProvider extends ImageProvider<AssetBundleImageKey> {
  /// Abstract const constructor. This constructor enables subclasses to provide
  /// const constructors so that they can be used in const expressions.
  const AssetBundleImageProvider();

  /// Converts a key into an [ImageStreamCompleter], and begins fetching the
  /// image using [loadAsync].
  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(AssetBundleImageKey key, DecoderCallback decode) {
    return MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter(
      codec: _loadAsync(key, decode),
      scale: key.scale,
      informationCollector: () sync* {
        yield DiagnosticsProperty<ImageProvider>('Image provider', this);
        yield DiagnosticsProperty<AssetBundleImageKey>('Image key', key);
      },
    );
  }

  /// Fetches the image from the asset bundle, decodes it, and returns a
  /// corresponding [ImageInfo] object.
  ///
  /// This function is used by [load].
  @protected
  Future<ui.Codec> _loadAsync(AssetBundleImageKey key, DecoderCallback decode) async {
    final ByteData data = await key.bundle.load(key.name);
    if (data == null)
      throw 'Unable to read data';
    return await decode(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  }
}

class _SizeAwareCacheKey {
  const _SizeAwareCacheKey(this.providerCacheKey, this.width, this.height);

  final Object providerCacheKey;

  final int width;

  final int height;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType)
      return false;
    final _SizeAwareCacheKey typedOther = other;
    return providerCacheKey == typedOther.providerCacheKey
        && width == typedOther.width
        && height == typedOther.height;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(providerCacheKey, width, height);
}

/// Instructs Flutter to decode the image at the specified dimensions
/// instead of at its native size.
///
/// This allows finer control of the size of the image in [ImageCache] and is
/// generally used to reduce the memory footprint of [ImageCache].
///
/// The decoded image may still be displayed at sizes other than the
/// cached size provided here.
class ResizeImage extends ImageProvider<_SizeAwareCacheKey> {
  /// Creates an ImageProvider that decodes the image to the specified size.
  ///
  /// The cached image will be directly decoded and stored at the resolution
  /// defined by `width` and `height`. The image will lose detail and
  /// use less memory if resized to a size smaller than the native size.
  const ResizeImage(
    this.imageProvider, {
    this.width,
    this.height,
  }) : assert(width != null || height != null);

  /// The [ImageProvider] that this class wraps.
  final ImageProvider imageProvider;

  /// The width the image should decode to and cache.
  final int width;

  /// The height the image should decode to and cache.
  final int height;

  /// Composes the `provider` in a [ResizeImage] only when `cacheWidth` and
  /// `cacheHeight` are not both null.
  ///
  /// When `cacheWidth` and `cacheHeight` are both null, this will return the
  /// `provider` directly.
  static ImageProvider<dynamic> resizeIfNeeded(int cacheWidth, int cacheHeight, ImageProvider<dynamic> provider) {
    if (cacheWidth != null || cacheHeight != null) {
      return ResizeImage(provider, width: cacheWidth, height: cacheHeight);
    }
    return provider;
  }

  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(_SizeAwareCacheKey key, DecoderCallback decode) {
    final DecoderCallback decodeResize = (Uint8List bytes, {int cacheWidth, int cacheHeight}) {
      assert(
        cacheWidth == null && cacheHeight == null,
        'ResizeImage cannot be composed with another ImageProvider that applies cacheWidth or cacheHeight.'
      );
      return decode(bytes, cacheWidth: width, cacheHeight: height);
    };
    return imageProvider.load(key.providerCacheKey, decodeResize);
  }

  @override
  Future<_SizeAwareCacheKey> obtainKey(ImageConfiguration configuration) async {
    final Object providerCacheKey = await imageProvider.obtainKey(configuration);
    return _SizeAwareCacheKey(providerCacheKey, width, height);
  }
}

/// Fetches the given URL from the network, associating it with the given scale.
///
/// The image will be cached regardless of cache headers from the server.
///
/// When a network image is used on the Web platform, the [cacheWidth] and
/// [cacheHeight] parameters of the [DecoderCallback] are ignored as the Web
/// engine delegates image decoding of network images to the Web, which does
/// not support custom decode sizes.
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [Image.network] for a shorthand of an [Image] widget backed by [NetworkImage].
// TODO(ianh): Find some way to honor cache headers to the extent that when the
// last reference to an image is released, we proactively evict the image from
// our cache if the headers describe the image as having expired at that point.
abstract class NetworkImage extends ImageProvider<NetworkImage> {
  /// Creates an object that fetches the image at the given URL.
  ///
  /// The arguments [url] and [scale] must not be null.
  const factory NetworkImage(String url, { double scale, Map<String, String> headers }) = network_image.NetworkImage;

  /// The URL from which the image will be fetched.
  String get url;

  /// The scale to place in the [ImageInfo] object of the image.
  double get scale;

  /// The HTTP headers that will be used with [HttpClient.get] to fetch image from network.
  ///
  /// When running flutter on the web, headers are not used.
  Map<String, String> get headers;

  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(NetworkImage key, DecoderCallback decode);
}

/// Decodes the given [File] object as an image, associating it with the given
/// scale.
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [Image.file] for a shorthand of an [Image] widget backed by [FileImage].
class FileImage extends ImageProvider<FileImage> {
  /// Creates an object that decodes a [File] as an image.
  ///
  /// The arguments must not be null.
  const FileImage(this.file, { this.scale = 1.0 })
    : assert(file != null),
      assert(scale != null);

  /// The file to decode into an image.
  final File file;

  /// The scale to place in the [ImageInfo] object of the image.
  final double scale;

  @override
  Future<FileImage> obtainKey(ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    return SynchronousFuture<FileImage>(this);
  }

  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(FileImage key, DecoderCallback decode) {
    return MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter(
      codec: _loadAsync(key, decode),
      scale: key.scale,
      informationCollector: () sync* {
        yield ErrorDescription('Path: ${file?.path}');
      },
    );
  }

  Future<ui.Codec> _loadAsync(FileImage key, DecoderCallback decode) async {
    assert(key == this);

    final Uint8List bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
    if (bytes.lengthInBytes == 0)
      return null;

    return await decode(bytes);
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType)
      return false;
    final FileImage typedOther = other;
    return file?.path == typedOther.file?.path
        && scale == typedOther.scale;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(file?.path, scale);

  @override
  String toString() => '$runtimeType("${file?.path}", scale: $scale)';
}

/// Decodes the given [Uint8List] buffer as an image, associating it with the
/// given scale.
///
/// The provided [bytes] buffer should not be changed after it is provided
/// to a [MemoryImage]. To provide an [ImageStream] that represents an image
/// that changes over time, consider creating a new subclass of [ImageProvider]
/// whose [load] method returns a subclass of [ImageStreamCompleter] that can
/// handle providing multiple images.
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [Image.memory] for a shorthand of an [Image] widget backed by [MemoryImage].
class MemoryImage extends ImageProvider<MemoryImage> {
  /// Creates an object that decodes a [Uint8List] buffer as an image.
  ///
  /// The arguments must not be null.
  const MemoryImage(this.bytes, { this.scale = 1.0 })
    : assert(bytes != null),
      assert(scale != null);

  /// The bytes to decode into an image.
  final Uint8List bytes;

  /// The scale to place in the [ImageInfo] object of the image.
  final double scale;

  @override
  Future<MemoryImage> obtainKey(ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    return SynchronousFuture<MemoryImage>(this);
  }

  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(MemoryImage key, DecoderCallback decode) {
    return MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter(
      codec: _loadAsync(key, decode),
      scale: key.scale,
    );
  }

  Future<ui.Codec> _loadAsync(MemoryImage key, DecoderCallback decode) {
    assert(key == this);

    return decode(bytes);
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType)
      return false;
    final MemoryImage typedOther = other;
    return bytes == typedOther.bytes
        && scale == typedOther.scale;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(bytes.hashCode, scale);

  @override
  String toString() => '$runtimeType(${describeIdentity(bytes)}, scale: $scale)';
}

/// Fetches an image from an [AssetBundle], associating it with the given scale.
///
/// This implementation requires an explicit final [assetName] and [scale] on
/// construction, and ignores the device pixel ratio and size in the
/// configuration passed into [resolve]. For a resolution-aware variant that
/// uses the configuration to pick an appropriate image based on the device
/// pixel ratio and size, see [AssetImage].
///
/// ## Fetching assets
///
/// When fetching an image provided by the app itself, use the [assetName]
/// argument to name the asset to choose. For instance, consider a directory
/// `icons` with an image `heart.png`. First, the [pubspec.yaml] of the project
/// should specify its assets in the `flutter` section:
///
/// ```yaml
/// flutter:
///   assets:
///     - icons/heart.png
/// ```
///
/// Then, to fetch the image and associate it with scale `1.5`, use
///
/// ```dart
/// AssetImage('icons/heart.png', scale: 1.5)
/// ```
///
/// ## Assets in packages
///
/// To fetch an asset from a package, the [package] argument must be provided.
/// For instance, suppose the structure above is inside a package called
/// `my_icons`. Then to fetch the image, use:
///
/// ```dart
/// AssetImage('icons/heart.png', scale: 1.5, package: 'my_icons')
/// ```
///
/// Assets used by the package itself should also be fetched using the [package]
/// argument as above.
///
/// If the desired asset is specified in the `pubspec.yaml` of the package, it
/// is bundled automatically with the app. In particular, assets used by the
/// package itself must be specified in its `pubspec.yaml`.
///
/// A package can also choose to have assets in its 'lib/' folder that are not
/// specified in its `pubspec.yaml`. In this case for those images to be
/// bundled, the app has to specify which ones to include. For instance a
/// package named `fancy_backgrounds` could have:
///
/// ```
/// lib/backgrounds/background1.png
/// lib/backgrounds/background2.png
/// lib/backgrounds/background3.png
/// ```
///
/// To include, say the first image, the `pubspec.yaml` of the app should specify
/// it in the `assets` section:
///
/// ```yaml
///   assets:
///     - packages/fancy_backgrounds/backgrounds/background1.png
/// ```
///
/// The `lib/` is implied, so it should not be included in the asset path.
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [Image.asset] for a shorthand of an [Image] widget backed by
///    [ExactAssetImage] when using a scale.
class ExactAssetImage extends AssetBundleImageProvider {
  /// Creates an object that fetches the given image from an asset bundle.
  ///
  /// The [assetName] and [scale] arguments must not be null. The [scale] arguments
  /// defaults to 1.0. The [bundle] argument may be null, in which case the
  /// bundle provided in the [ImageConfiguration] passed to the [resolve] call
  /// will be used instead.
  ///
  /// The [package] argument must be non-null when fetching an asset that is
  /// included in a package. See the documentation for the [ExactAssetImage] class
  /// itself for details.
  const ExactAssetImage(
    this.assetName, {
    this.scale = 1.0,
    this.bundle,
    this.package,
  }) : assert(assetName != null),
       assert(scale != null);

  /// The name of the asset.
  final String assetName;

  /// The key to use to obtain the resource from the [bundle]. This is the
  /// argument passed to [AssetBundle.load].
  String get keyName => package == null ? assetName : 'packages/$package/$assetName';

  /// The scale to place in the [ImageInfo] object of the image.
  final double scale;

  /// The bundle from which the image will be obtained.
  ///
  /// If the provided [bundle] is null, the bundle provided in the
  /// [ImageConfiguration] passed to the [resolve] call will be used instead. If
  /// that is also null, the [rootBundle] is used.
  ///
  /// The image is obtained by calling [AssetBundle.load] on the given [bundle]
  /// using the key given by [keyName].
  final AssetBundle bundle;

  /// The name of the package from which the image is included. See the
  /// documentation for the [ExactAssetImage] class itself for details.
  final String package;

  @override
  Future<AssetBundleImageKey> obtainKey(ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    return SynchronousFuture<AssetBundleImageKey>(AssetBundleImageKey(
      bundle: bundle ?? configuration.bundle ?? rootBundle,
      name: keyName,
      scale: scale,
    ));
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType)
      return false;
    final ExactAssetImage typedOther = other;
    return keyName == typedOther.keyName
        && scale == typedOther.scale
        && bundle == typedOther.bundle;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(keyName, scale, bundle);

  @override
  String toString() => '$runtimeType(name: "$keyName", scale: $scale, bundle: $bundle)';
}

// A completer used when resolving an image fails sync.
class _ErrorImageCompleter extends ImageStreamCompleter {
  _ErrorImageCompleter();

  void setError({
    DiagnosticsNode context,
    dynamic exception,
    StackTrace stack,
    InformationCollector informationCollector,
    bool silent = false,
  }) {
    reportError(
      context: context,
      exception: exception,
      stack: stack,
      informationCollector: informationCollector,
      silent: silent,
    );
  }
}

/// The exception thrown when the HTTP request to load a network image fails.
class NetworkImageLoadException implements Exception {
  /// Creates a [NetworkImageLoadException] with the specified http status
  /// [code] and the [uri]
  NetworkImageLoadException({@required this.statusCode, @required this.uri})
      : assert(uri != null),
        assert(statusCode != null),
        _message = 'HTTP request failed, statusCode: $statusCode, $uri';

  /// The HTTP status code from the server.
  final int statusCode;

  /// A human-readable error message.
  final String _message;

  /// Resolved URL of the requested image.
  final Uri uri;

  @override
  String toString() => _message;
}
````

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a solution to this or have moved on, but leaving a comment here incase someone comes across this question as I have, since I've recently run into this issue too. It looks like this issue was fixed in `0.6.0-alpha.1` (https://github.com/mchome/flutter_advanced_networkimage/issues/127)